# Automatic authentication of users on web applications using Okta+SAML

Tags: iframe, cookies, cross-domain, saml, okta

I have a web portal, which uses Okta+SAML for authentication. The web portal is required to automatically authenticate a user for web applications such as LucidChart and Box, then show iframed folders and charts from them without showing the web applications' main site.

Here is some background info about what I've tried so far:

1. Okta+SAML can only authenticate the web applications when the user visits an Okta-generated redirect URL after signing in to their Okta account. The problem is that I don't want the user to have to click on multiple links and open the full web applications before they can view the iframed content. This should happen automatically.

I got around this by opening the Okta redirect URLs in hidden iframes so that the web applications authenticate and load unnoticed.

However, certain web browsers (Safari being the main culprit) block third-party cookies, therefore the iframed content will not be able to access the authentication cookies set by the hidden iframes and will return a HTTP401 (or some other error).

2. I got around the third-party cookie issue by doing the following:

   - the user clicks the Login button to sign in to the web portal
   - the click event fires JavaScript which uses window.open() to open LucidChart and Box domains in separate tabs
   - after waiting *a few seconds* for the pages to load, they are not deemed "third-party" any more
   - the web portal then uses [tabbed_window].close() to close the tabs it opened (+ various hacks required to close tabs on iPhones)
   - the user is then redirected to the portal's home page.

On slow connections, the *few seconds* can time out and therefore this fails to make the sites "visited".

Also, different versions of iOS+Safari seem to handle window.open and window.close differently, so every time a new version of iOS is released, I have to test to make sure this all still works.

I understand the need for cross-domain cookie and iframe policies, but I legitimately have the need to circumvent this.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Have you found a better way for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. There needs to be a standard way to authenticate across web applications that aren't part of an intranet.